# Как получить доступ к контролам стороннего приложения?

Tags: c#, winforms

Приветствую!

Необходимио из приложения, написанного с использованием Framework 2.0, получить доступ к контролам. А именно прочитать свойство text, получить дочерние элементы, если это TreeView и т.п.

Буду благодарен за ссылки или примеры, хотя бы издалека напоминающие подобные действия.

Спасибо.

Comment: Забыл уточнить. Стороннее преложение не WinForms. Думаю, что написано на Visual C++.

Comment: с помощью Microsoft Active Accessibility (MSAA). пример [тут](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2011/05/17/enabling-ui-testing-for-third-party-winforms-custom-controls-1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, можно ли это сделать через Windows Forms, но через WinAPI можно. Насколько я знаю, он тоже доступен в C# и находится в каком-то пространсве имён, не помню каком.

Алгоритм такой: посылаешь сообщение WM_GETTEXT элементу управления, передавая указатель на массив байтов. В нём у тебя получится C-строка. Теперь её надо как-то перевести в string. Я плохо знаю .NET, не могу сказать как. Эта строка и будет текстом элемента управления.

Получение дочерних элементов через WinAPI посложнее. Не знаю, как это делается.

Comment: Интересное предложение. Покурю в этом направлении.

Comment: @pavelnik проще с помощью Automation. пример на C# [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/289680/#482055)

Answer (score 0):

Есть отличная библиотека [NUnit Forms](http://nunitforms.sourceforge.net/), она позволяет управлять чужими формами. Правда ее основное предназначение это тестирования UI. Но я думаю подобную задачу она решитю

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Судя по описанию подходит только для WinForms.