# Как получить данные из чужого WPF приложения во время выполнения?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Есть некоторое WPF приложение. В этом приложении есть таблица данных. У меня возникла острая необходимость расширить функционал приложения на основе его данных. Экспорта в нем нету. Поэтому пришлось писать приложение которое бы вытягивало данные в run-time. Возникла только одна проблем — это wpf. Я могу получить только `hwnd` главного окна, а что делать дальше ума не приложу.

Вообщем вопрос, есть ли какой нибудь изящный способ вытащить данные из WPF приложения во время выполнения?

---

**update**

даю ответ:
после пары дней шерстения msdn'a было выяснено, что win32 в wpf уже не поддерживается. Следовательно искать хэнделы окон нет смысла. Приложения работают в protected mode и просто так доступ к компонентам не получишь.
Но есть выход Automation!

http://www.universalthread.com/ViewPageArticle.aspx?ID=199

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/289028/White-An-UI-Automation-tool-for-windows-applicatio

а также ищущим будет полезна утилита UI Spy

Comment: То, что вы описываете в апдейте — довольно грязный путь. Если приложение не прописывает `AutomationId` (а оно вполне может это делать), вам будет непросто достучаться до нужного UI-элемента. Кроме того, как вы собираетесь пройти _дальше_ — от UI к VM и моделям? Это снова требует reverse engineering большой части приложения.

Comment: @VladD 
- Насчет FAQ, почему-то коменты в низ больше не добавляются, процетирую:- Общение на форуме происходит в формате вопросов и ответов. а не советов!

- от UI к VM и моделям? Как закончу проект отпишусь.

Comment: @vancouver: Есть лимит комметариев: 4 на каждую ветку.

---
Мой ответ — это именно ответ. «Никак.» Остальное — объяснение, почему именно так, а не иначе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данные из WPF приложения можно извлечь с помощью Automation.
Например, окно слева - это WPF приложение с DataGrid'ом. А окно справа - это WinForms приложение, в котором выводятся данные из WPF приложения, включая данные из DataGrid, в формате xml.
Код WinForms приложения ниже под скриншотом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
// Microsoft (R) Roslyn C# Compiler version 1.1.0.51204
#r "System.Windows.Forms"
#r "WindowsBase"
#r "UIAutomationTypes"
#r "UIAutomationClient"
#r "System.Xml.Linq"

using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(System.Drawing.Point p);

static void Fill(XElement x, AutomationElement a) {
    var xn = new XElement("e", new XAttribute("class", a.Current.ClassName));
    x.Add(xn);
    xn.Add(new XAttribute("name", a.Current.Name));
    var aes = a.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);
    foreach (var ac in aes.OfType<AutomationElement>()) Fill(xn, ac);
}

var frm = new Form() { Width = 800, Height = 500, TopMost = true };
var rtb = new RichTextBox() { Parent = frm, Dock = DockStyle.Fill, WordWrap = false };
var hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = 500, Enabled = true }
    .Tick += (s, e) => {
        var pos = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
        var h = WindowFromPoint(pos);
        if (h != hwnd) {
            hwnd = h;
            var a = AutomationElement.FromHandle(hwnd);
            var x = new XElement("root");
            Fill(x, a);
            rtb.Text = x.ToString(); }};
frm.ShowDialog();
```

---

Для компиляции кода и запуска приложения, например, в Visual Studio Community 2015 надо открыть `View - Other Windows - C# Interactive`, скопировать в него код и нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Visual Studio Community 2015 - бесплатная версия, ее можно скачать [тут](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146).

Comment: спасибо вам за подробный ответ.
в моём конечном решении было: dotPeek64 + CInject. 
Если кому понадобится гуглите инфы по обоим продуктам много.

Answer (score 4):

Никак.

Если приложение не предоставило вам API, вы *не можете* правильным образом получить из него данные.

Есть несколько грязных путей, из которых самый простой — декомпилировать приложение, разобраться в его логике, и модифицировать (или научиться понимать формат его выходных данных).

Приложение скорее всего *не* рассчитано на взаимодействие с другими программами. WPF framework тоже не даст вам данные просто так.

Лучше всего обратиться к разработчикам и купить у них API (если вы не фрилансер, деньги — не ваша проблема, а вашего работодателя) или заказать нужную функциональность. Давайте играть по цивилизованным правилам, а?

Comment: я не могу играть по цивилизованным правилам когда против меня играют по не цивилизованным правилам :) .

я понимаю что просто так не даст, поэтому и спросил о самом изящном способе. просто пока я до него (способа) доберусь придется половину msdn перечитать.

насчет декомпиляции уже думал, но что-то подсказывало мне что это не самый простой способ.

Comment: > против меня играют по не цивилизованным правилам

1. Нам откуда это знать
2. С трудом себе представляю ситуацию, где в качестве ответных действий предпринимается такое

Comment: @vancouver: Простите, а кто играет против вас?

Разработчики WPF-приложения или начальство? Разработчики никому не обязаны давать API, если они не хотят, чтобы с их программой работали, надо уважать их выбор.

Если начальство, то вас ведь не держат в рабстве, да? Вы всегда можете сказать начальнику, что не желаете нарушать закон, и уйти в более цивилизованную компанию. Начальство, которое не уважает труд чужих программистов, вряд ли будет уважать труд собственных.

Comment: где я вообще написал о начальстве?, все это делается для себя! ребята у меня нет слов это полный писец, вместо сайта ответов, какой-то сайт СОВЕТОВ!!!

@VladD В некоторых случаях обязаны и еще как обязаны давать свой API или хотя бы э к с п о р т данных, это правила хорошего тона, а не шантажировать покупкой новых модулей, тем более если за ПО и так идут пассивные платежи. А если правила хорошего тона нарушаются, то это хрен знает что, а не цивилизованные правила.

@Fike если делаете предположение значит знаете или делаете вид.

зы если не знаете что ответить пройдите мимо. это мой вам СОВЕТ!

Comment: @vancouver Если люди вам говорят, что вы что-то делаете не так, то, возможно, вы и вправду делаете что-то не так (такое случается).

> А если правила хорошего тона нарушаются, то это хрен знает что, а не цивилизованные правила.

То можно и в рыло дать, если со мной не поздоровались, ага.
Большое количество софта живет за счет того, что базовые функции продает задешево/отдает бесплатно, а на доп.функциях отыгрывается и живет в плюс.

Comment: @vancouver: Начнём с того, что я такой же посетитель сайта, как и вы, и не обязан отвечать так, как нравится вам. Если вам не нравится мой ответ — просто поставьте минус, делов-то!

Во-вторых, и разработчики софта тоже не обязаны давать вам API. Никто вас не заставляет пользоваться их софтом; если вам не нравится софт без публичного API, просто перейдите на другой софт.

Если у меня есть машина, я не обязан давать вам покататься. И этим самым я _не нарушаю_ никакие правила хорошего тона.

Comment: @Fike отдача не замучает? не надо мне рассказывать за счет чего живет софт. я и сам прекрасно знаю. 
если вы не внимательно читали то прочтите еще раз... и еще раз... и еще раз... это помогает... пассивные платежи... иногда очень даже обязаны делать хотя бы экспорт данных, а не заниматься шантажом.

Comment: @VladD http://hashcode.ru/faq/#heading1

Comment: @vancouver: И что? Какая из строчек FAQ противоречит сказанному мной?

Comment: @VladD _"Никак"_ -- а реализация/поддержка Automation была в WPF не с самого начала?

Comment: @Stack: Она там уже достаточно давно (я не знаю, когда она появилась), но вытянуть с помощью Automation можно лишь строки из UI, а реальные данные — это всё-таки модель.

Comment: @VladD _"можно лишь строки из UI, а реальные данные — это всё-таки модель"_ -- т.е. если в объекте есть FirstName и LastName, но в UI выводится FullName, то это не подходит, т.к. нужны именно значения FirstName и LastName?

Comment: @Stack: Ну, некоторые данные программа может и вовсе не выводить. Например, поле `Password`. И если объектов много, и используется виртуализиция списков, то и не все объекты. А ещё если используется master-detail view или как его там...

Comment: @VladD _"Например, Password"_ -- с этим понятно. а про виртуализацию - интересно, не проверял. возможно что при обращение через Automation выводятся все данные, даже если включена виртуализация.

Comment: @Stack: По идее не должно, виртуализация должна лишь обходить существующий DOM, а на уровне visual tree незагруженных объектов просто нету. Но это рассуждения на уровне догадок, если вы проверите, запостите информацию куда-нибудь (лучше наверное в ваш ответ, это увеличит его ценность).

Comment: @Stack: Тьфу, опечатка. Не «виртуализация должна лишь обходить существующий DOM», а «Automation должно лишь обходить существующий DOM»

Comment: @VladD _"если вы проверите, запостите информацию"_ -- ок.

Comment: @Stack: Спасибо заранее. Мне тоже интересно, как оно там устроено.